# Google login user profile not updated to Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am new to Xcode and I am working on my Google sign-in project. After successfully logging in with google, I cannot find the user profile in firebase. I think I am missing the code for uploading user credentials to firebase. I can barely understand the documentation and I don't know what to do. By the way, how can I navigate to another view controller after signing in? I tried lots of ways but none of them work. Any help is appreciated.

**My AppDelegate code**:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate{

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.clientID = "//I have it in my actual code"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
        
        return true
    }
    
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
          print(error)
          return
        }

        guard
          let authentication = user?.authentication,
          let idToken = authentication.idToken
        else {
          return
        }

        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

    }
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

***The code of the log-in view controller***

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var gooleButton: GIDSignInButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        gooleButton.style = .wide
        gooleButton.colorScheme = .dark

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see your code signs the user in with Google to get the credentials, but then doesn't call `signIn(with: )` which is needed in order to sign in to Firebase Authentication.

Have a look at [Step 3: authenticate with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin#3_authenticate_with_firebase). While the code there looks a bit intimidating, that's mostly because it handled many different cases. At its minimum you can sign in to Firebase with your credentials by doing:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
    if let error = error {
      let authError = error as NSError
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      return
    }
    // User is signed in
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I got a problem after pasting the code saying "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'showMessagePrompt'" I am a bit confused about what the showMessagePrompt is? How do I fix it.

Comment: You can use whatever method you want to show a message. I updated to use `print`.

Comment: That works! Thank you. Do you know how I could navigate to another view controller after signing in? I've tried "self.inputViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMain", sender: self)" in App Delegate, but not getting any respond.